# Ajax / PHP / Json: One GET parameter is missing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem because one parameter (out of 2) is always missing on the server side (when I send them via AJAX to it).

My JS code looks like:

```
function import_websql(user_id) {
    var db = openDatabase("database", "1.0", "table", 2*1024*1024);
    var favourite_ids = "";

    if (window.openDatabase){
    db.transaction(
        function(t){ // This is the callback with "t" as the transaction object
            t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM favourites', [], function (t, results) {
              var len = results.rows.length, i;
              for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                favourite_ids += results.rows.item(i).id + "t";
              }
            });
        }, onError, onReadyTransaction(user_id,favourite_ids)
    );
    } else{
        alert("Your smartphone is too weird!");
    };
}

function onReadyTransaction(user_id,favourite_ids) {
    alert(favourite_ids);
    send_websql(user_id,favourite_ids)
}

function onError() {
    alert("error");
}

function send_websql(user_id,favourite_ids){    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fct.import_websql.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {user_id: user_id, favourite_ids: favourite_ids},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){

        },
        success: function(data) 
        {
            if(data) {
                alert(favourite_ids + "Worked!" + data);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error: " + data);
            }
        },
        complete: function(data){

        },
        error: function(xhr,textStatus,err) 
        {
          console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
          console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
          console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
          console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
          console.log("error: " + err);
        }
    });
}
```

And my PHP looks like:

```
<?php 
include_once('database_connect.php');
include_once('clean.php');

$user_id = clean($_GET['user_id']);
$favourite_ids = clean($_GET['favourite_ids']);

$favourite_ids_arr = explode('t', $favourite_ids);
array_pop($favourite_ids_arr);

foreach ($favourite_ids_arr as &$favourite_id) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO map_favourite_user_bookmark (map_favourite_user_bookmark_favourite_id, map_favourite_user_bookmark_user_id) VALUES ($favourite_id, $user_id)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql = "UPDATE user_info SET user_websql_imported = 1 WHERE user_id = $user_id)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}

$response = "ok" . $favourite_ids;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

'Funny' thing is that on the JS side before I send the data EVERYTHING exists (and would be `alerted`), but on the PHP side the `favourite_ids` are completely missing (can't `echo` them, can't process them, and they are not given back... like they don't exist).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $recipe_ids \ $favourite_ids messed up variable renaming

Comment: Exactly **WHY** are you bulding a `t`-delimited string, when you could quite easily just send a json-encoded ARRAY to the client? that'd remove any need to build strings/explode, plus the odds that your string naturally contains a `t` which would cause the explode to split things up in the wrong place.

Comment: @Dagon thank you, but i changed them recently. in my code they all have the same variable name, that's not the problem!

Comment: so you post code your not actully using and expect us to be able to help you debug it?

Comment: @MarcB sorry, i made this "quick and dirty" because this functionality (import the websql database) is just needed for some days to weeks

Comment: @Dagon sorry for the inconvenience. i changed them on the fly, because i already wanted to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the database API is asynchronous, so you will execute your ajax call while the database transaction has not yet finished.

One way to solve it, is to put the ajax call in the callback of the query function.

Comment: thanks. i updated my question with the improvement you suggested, but now it already lost the `favourite_ids` on the JS side...

Comment: @JohnBrunner That sounds like an error somewhere, do you get any messages in the console. It would also help to post the modified code under the original code.

Comment: the problem was that my `onReadyTransaction` was quicker than the code after the `for` loop in the `sql` function. i made now a function call after the `for` loop in the `executeSql` and now everything works fine! thanks for your comment!